# Tableau Link sorting across Worksheets

Tags: sorting, tableau-api

Is it possible in Tableau 9 to link sorting on a certain dashboard? I have 3 different worksheets on the same page all with the same rows. Is it possible to link them so when a sort is pressed on one of the worksheets that the other two are sorted the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://community.tableau.com/thread/138362 I can't paste an example but this link sums up using a calculated field creation how to do it.